# Adaptively Displaying Images Inline Drupal 7

Tags: media, theming

For Drupal 7.14 I've been trying to display images inline adaptively to a content type. In my content type I have a long text and summary field and an image field. I'm using the Adaptive Image Styles (ais) module. I upload the image and then insert the image using the insert module. I'm using full HTML without any text editor. But when I insert the code it does not display adaptively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to get AIS working for adapting with inline images and shadow box. It can be done through Wysiwyg (see here for instructions: http://drupal.org/node/1555376)  or I just insert this code in the image tag: class="adaptive media-image attr_*typeof*_foaf:Image img_*fid*_1172 img__view_mode__media_adaptive attr_*format*_media_adaptive" typeof="foaf:Image". From what I can tell none of the other adaptive modules can do this. I checked it in Adaptive Image and it does not do inline images. An example of this working can be seen at: `http://173.236.7.153/~ssanalyt/drupal/consulting-areas/business`